Locking a resource properly to avoid conflicts during parallel test execution
How can I lock particular keywords in a common keyword robot file. so that while doing parallel testsuite execution using pabot conflicts will not be raised.
I used acquire lock and release lock for that specific keywords. imported pabot.pabotlib in that robot file.
run the command:
pabot --processes 6 --pabotlib --resourcefile 

Wecome to stackoverflow!
Please take a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask docs.  This question,  as is, can't be answered due to lack of context, and is likely getting downvoted or closed soon.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
